# Is average of dependent identically distributed $O_p(1)$ variables still $O_p(1)$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Suppose we have a series of random variables $\{r_{i,T}\}_{i=1}^T$, where $r_{i,T}$ follow the same distribution regardless of $T$, but may not be independent for different $i$ when $T$ is fixed. We know $r_{i,T} = O_p(1)$ when $T$ goes to infinity, can we claim that $\sum_{i=1}^Tr_{i,T} = O_p(T)$ when $T$ goes to infinity?
Thank you!

Comment: Is $\{r_{i,T}\}_{i=1}^T$ a [triangular array](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~xshi/econ715/Lecture_9_local_power.pdf)?

Comment: Yes! $i = 1,\dots,T$ and $T=1,\dots,\infty$

Comment: Note that these are *sums,* not averages.  In light of the reference to "average" in the title, did you perhaps forget to divide by $T$?

Comment: Thanks, whuber. Based on the definition of big O, $X = O_p(T)$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{T}X = O_p(1)$? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My intuition: 1. If $\forall T, \{r_{i,T}\}_i$ are i.i.d., then the claim should be true. 2. If $\forall T, \{r_{i,T}\}_i$ are the same (i.e., as random variables, $r_{1,T} = \dots = r_{T,T}$), then the claim should still be true. Since the two extreme cases hold, I believe it is true?